# Gene ontology e Rede de interação gênica no R

Tags: r, ontologia

Olá,

Eu tenho um dataset de expressão gênica organizado da seguinte maneira:

```
  Gene      FC12h        QV12H           FC10d             QV10d                   
  Rp1      -0,371        0,797           2,647             0,718
  Sox17     15,200       0,438           2,946             0,445    
  Mrpl15   -1,789        0,218           0,752             0,004
```

FC representa o folding change e QV o q-value para  duas situações: 12 horas e 10 dias. 
Eu já procurei muito, baixei pacotes e não consegui fazer uma análise da expressão diferencial desses genes; o máximo que consegui foi fazer um heatmap e separar os genes diferencialmente expressos para cada situação. Preciso fazer um gene ontology com esses genes diferencialmente expressos e também uma rede de interação gênica. Alguém de algum pacote, alguma dica, qualquer coisa que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Esta pergunta está um pouco ampla. Ao fazer comparação de expressão gênica, é interessante saber qual tecnologia foi utilizada para sequenciamento dos genes. Os valores colocados aqui já são o log2 fold-change? Já tentou procurar análises realizas por outras pessoas que utilizaram a mesma tecnologia de sequenciamento? [Dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.